# How to switch back to default content (or switch iframes) in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have to navigate a website which is build by a framework, and kind of "a special snowflake"

it consists of up to 3 iframes, but only one is "active" the others are set to display: none. 
everytime i move from one page to another, the new page is loaded in another iframe.

Now, if i want to access an element in the new active iframe i get an error "Element not found"

with Webdriver i solved the Problem by doing the following

```
WebElement currentFrame = _driver.findElement(By
            .xpath("//iframe[not(contains(@style,'display: none'))]"));
_driver.switchTo().frame(currentFrame);
....
Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
....
WebElement currentFrame = _driver.findElement(By
            .xpath("//iframe[not(contains(@style,'display: none'))]"));
_driver.switchTo().frame(currentFrame);
```

in Selenium IDE i managed to find my first frame with

```
Command: selectFrame
Target: //iframe[not(contains(@style,'display: none'))]
```

but at this point i am stuck.
if i go and click the command-sequence myself everything is fine, but when i try to do the whole testcase, it doesn't find any elements in the new iframe i even tried to pause, and wait 10 seconds in case the new frame hasn't finished loading yet, but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: try target: xpath=//iframe[not(contains(@style,'display: none'))]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems i am able to switch to the default content by simply doing :

```
Command :selectWindow
```

No Target, no Value